# Dynamic Routing React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Repo: `https://github.com/alxdelgado/reddit-clone`

Problem: A view containing more information about an individual post (including comments for the post).

App.js

```
// import dependencies;
import React from 'react'; 
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { Router, Route, Switch, Link, useParams, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
import theme from '../theme';
import GlobalStyle from '../globalStyle';
import Home from '../components/Home/Home';
import Posts from '../components/Posts/Posts';
import Comment from '../components/Comments/Comment';
import Header from '../components/Header/Component';
import HeaderNavLink from '../components/Header/NavLink';

export default function App(props) {
    // theme provider adds "dark theme" to the app; WIP - not functional yet. 
    
    return (
        
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme(props.dark)}>
                    <>
                        <Header/>
                        <GlobalStyle />
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                                <Route exact path='/posts' component={Posts} />
                                <Route name="comments" path='/comments' component={Comment} />
                            </Switch>
                    </> 
            </ThemeProvider>
        
    )
}
```

Posts.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Suspense } from 'react'; 
import regeneratorRuntime from 'regenerator-runtime';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { REDDIT_USER_AGENT, REDDIT_CLIENT_ID, REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET, REDDIT_REFRESH_TOKEN } from 'babel-dotenv';


// import components; 
import PostList from '../PostList/PostList';
import Loading from '../../assets/loader.gif';


// styled wrapper; 
const Wrapper = styled.div`
 
    align-items: center; 
    margin: 0 10vw; 

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        margin: 0 5vw; 
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        display: block;
        margin: 0; 
    }
`;

// fetch all "hot" posts; 
export default function Posts(props) {
    console.log("Posts -->", props);

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // snoowrap api wrapper;
        // Docs: --> https://not-an-aardvark.github.io/snoowrap/index.html
        const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');
        // creating the snoowrap requester with OAuth credentials;
        const r = new snoowrap({
            userAgent: REDDIT_USER_AGENT,
            clientId: REDDIT_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET, 
            refreshToken: REDDIT_REFRESH_TOKEN,
        });
        
        // fetch all "hot" posts; 
        // docs: https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/snoowrap
        // write the async function to fetch the data;
        
        
        const getRedditHot = async () => {
            if (error) {
                setError(true); 
            } else {
                setError(false);
                let response = await r.getHot('wec');
                const posts = response; 
                setPosts(posts);
                // console.log("getRedditHot -->", posts);
            }
        }   

        getRedditHot();
        // console.log("getRedditHot end of useEffect -->", posts); 
    }, []);

    console.log("getRedditHot outside useEffect -->", posts);

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={Loading}>
            <Wrapper>
                {posts.map((post, idx, ...otherPostProps) => {
                        return <PostList key={idx} props={post} {...otherPostProps} />
                })}
            </Wrapper>
        </Suspense>
    )
    
};
```

PostList.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'; 
import { Route, Switch, Link, useRouteMatch, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

// import components; 
import ErrorBoundary from '../../util/ErrorBoundary';
import Loading from '../../assets/loader.gif';

// styled components;
const List = styled.ul`
    list-style: none; 
    border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.border}; 
    border-radius: 5px;

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        border-top: none; 
        border-left: none; 
        border-right: none; 
        border-radius: 0; 
    }
`;

const RedditTitle = styled.h1`
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1rem;  

`; 

export default function PostList(props) {
    // console.log("PostList -->", props);

    // let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

    // having trouble dynamically routing a link to each post 
    // that takes the user to a view of the individual posts, comments, likes, etc. 
    // Docs: --> https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v0.13.6/doc/03%20Components/Link.md#params

    return (
        <ErrorBoundary>
            <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>
                <List key={props.props.id}>
                    <h5>{props.props.subreddit_name_prefixed}</h5>
                    <RedditTitle>{props.props.title}</RedditTitle>
                    {/* <img src={props.props.thumbnail}/> */}
                    <li>
                        // my mental breakdown starts here;
                        <Link to={`/comments/${props.props.comments._uri}`}>More</Link>
                    </li>
                </List>
            </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    )
};
```

HERE IS THE PROBLEM -- how do you dynamically route to another component with a view containing the details and comments of that individual post? Because I am using the "snoowrap API" I have to hit another individual endpoint in order to get the comments for that post but I have no way of matching the ID's through match params.

Comment.js (just incase you need to see this)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import regeneratorRuntime from 'regenerator-runtime'; 
import styled from 'styled-components';

// import components; 
import CommentList from '../CommentList/CommentList';
import { sortData } from '../../util/sort';
// import env var;
import { REDDIT_USER_AGENT, REDDIT_CLIENT_ID, REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET, REDDIT_REFRESH_TOKEN } from 'babel-dotenv';

// styled component;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
 
    align-items: center; 
    margin: 0 10vw; 

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        margin: 0 5vw; 
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        display: block;
        margin: 0; 
    }
`;

export default function Comment(props) {
    console.log("Comment component -->", props);

    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // snoowrap api wrapper;
        // Docs: --> https://not-an-aardvark.github.io/snoowrap/index.html
        const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');
        // creating the snoowrap requester with OAuth credentials;
        const r = new snoowrap({
            userAgent: REDDIT_USER_AGENT,
            clientId: REDDIT_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET, 
            refreshToken: REDDIT_REFRESH_TOKEN,
        });

        // fetch all "comments" of a subreddit post; 
        // docs: https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/snoowrap
        // write the async function to fetch the data;

        const getRedditComments = async () => {
            if (error) {
                setLoading(true);
                setError(true);
            } else {
                setError(false);
                setLoading(false);
                let response = await r.getSubreddit('wec').getNewComments();
                const sortedData = sortData(response); 
                const comments = sortedData; 
                setComments(comments); 
                // console.log("getRedditComments -->", comments);
            }

        }

        getRedditComments();
    }, []); 

    console.log(" getRedditCommments outside useEffect -->", comments);

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <CommentList props={comments} />
        </Wrapper>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what [route params](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) are for. Update your route to take a param:

```
<Route name="comments" path='/comments/:postid' component={Comment} />
```

Link to the comments for a specific post:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to={`comments/${thePostId}`}>View Comments</Link>
```

And [use that](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) in your Comments component to fetch the corresponding comments:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Comment (props) {
  const {postid} = useParams();
  // do stuff with postid...
}
```